# Do I need to use session in every page?

Tags: php

If I am using login functionalilty do I need to start session for every page on top from log in until log out?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Comment: yes if the pages are different php pages

Comment: yes ..! you have to start session in every page.

Comment: Does every session which starts on every page create a new session id? If so how is logged in user recognised? @Exprator

Comment: @DharmendraSingh

Comment: Yes every session have different session id. But you have your session variables which you have to store your all logged in user information .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate file for this and include it in every pages.
create a file 'session.php'

session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy()) // Destroying All Sessions
{
header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

Then include it in every other page you want to use session.

```
include('session.php');
```